# How to install node.js and npm on linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I am following a tutorial for a course, and in a specific step of it, I am supposed to install node and node.js using these specific instructions.

[image]

but i'm confused with the first step. I don't understand how to enter that in the terminal. What is the `<<EOL`? Can someone explain it or show it as a 1 liner so I can use it. I tried just copy pasting that, but then it fails at a later step for installing npm, and I get issues about having broken packages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/. See [man page for "Here documents"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: In short to fix that error, run this command `sudo apt -f install && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y nodejs npm`

Answer (score 1):

Just use node version manager (nvm) which is my recommendation.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

After installing nvm run `nvm install 6.9.4` or whatever version you want.  Then run `nvm alias default 6.9.4`

Comment: You should get npm with the nodejs installation itself. You don't need to install npm separately. See this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-4/tutorial. Try running the last line without doing `apt-get install npm`

Comment: that is probably the issue.

Comment: It looks like node may not have installed.  Did you try `node --version`?  It should give you a version number if it installed.  Also, [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) is the page for installing node with a package manager.